# Routing General Midi drum kit to Maschine from Logic

Tags: midi, logic-pro

I am using Logic Pro. I have imported a midi file. One of the tracks is the drum kit.

I have a plug in VST for a Korg Wave Station. If I select a drum kit from the Korg VST the drums play correctly.

I want to change the kit to a kit in Maschine.

When I load up Maschine from within Logic Pro into the track, It tries to play all the drums from just the first assigned drum sample, usually the kick drum, whereas I wanted it to trigger the sounds across the various channels in Maschine.

I thought perhaps I needed to use one of the midi ext kits in Maschine. But none of those make any sound at all.

Is there a way to route a General Midi drum line into Maschine so I can use the Maschine kits to play the drum beats?

Load MIDI file with drums into Logic and assign Korg Wavestation to track.
[image: Load MIDI file with drums into Logic and assign Korg Wavestation to track.]

Korg Wavestation with Kit Assigned

[image: Korg Wavestation with Kit Assigned]

Copy track and assign Maschine to track

[image: Copy track and assign Maschine to track]

Maschine with Kit assigned to tracks inside Maschine. The kick (1) is highlighted and will be the one used for all sounds.

[image: Maschine with Kit assigned to tracks inside Maschine]

Split the track by note in order to place each drum on a separate logic track

[image: Split the track by note in order to place each drum on a separate logic track]

After splitting the track in Logic.

[image: After splitting the track in Logic.]

At this point while the tracks are all split, they are all tied to one instance of Maschine. Whatever I do inside maschine, affects all these channels.

This is where I think I am missing something. I was hoping to be able to go through and assign the first drum track in Logic to the kick in Maschine. The second track in Logic to the snare in maschine etc. etc.

What I can do from this point is add 16 new software tracks into Logic  and highlight all the drum tracks in Logic and option drag them all into the new tracks. Doing this splits the tracks into separate tracks. I can then go through each track and load up a kit in Maschine and highlight whatever drum sample I am wanting to play.

The problem with this is you are loading 16 or more instances of Maschine, which very quickly ends up with out of memory errors.

I thought at the stage of having split the tracks but not copied the tracks, There might be some way to assign the Logic track to a specific "pad" in Maschine. so that it played the right sound without having to go that extra step.

Comment: Hi Bob, I have added some more detail, as much as I can think of that is relevant with screen shots, Hope this helps and thank you.

Comment: Wow! You’ve certainly given us plenty of detail. I’ll have a read through later. I’m pretty good with Logic; hopefully we might have some NI experts on here too. Maschine is one plug-in I haven’t used.

Comment: It seems crazy to have to have separate instances of Maschine for each sound. I’ve never known any drum plugin work like this...